# prove that exists connected and bridgeless subgraph

Tags: graph-theory

I would be glad for help in this question which I have been tried to solve and looking for answer: Given an undirected,connected graph ,G=(V,E). if G is bridgeless (definition added below) ,then there exists connected bidgeless subgraph G' such that , G' = (V, E′) ,
E′ ⊆ E and |E′ | ≤ 2|V | − 2.
(we can use DFS algorithm,if it helps).

definition of a bridge:an edge that if we remove it,the number of connected components will grow by 1. Thank you!

Comment: One way is to use the fact that there is a cycle passing through any vertex, and try a greedy approach.

Comment: hey,thank you for the comment :) can you explain further without the greedy approach? because that's not in my curriculum in the course(and also I havent learned it yet).

Comment: A greedy approach is a sequence of choices where you don't have to worry about your choices later. In a greedy approach, you never have to cancel a choice you have made since every sequence of choices should get you a correct result. Here, try to construct a collection of cycles passing through each node. See if you get a graph meeting the conditions. With a correct construction, you should get what you want.